# I want to track and save in a database how many times a Java function is called. What is the best way to do that?

Tags: javascript, java, analytics, user-input, tracking

I have a Java backend and javascript+HTML/CSS in the front end. I want to implement something to measure how many times a button is clicked or a functionality is used and store that data in some data-store. I don't want to use Google Analytics or other third party tools.

Comment: There is a difference between counting on the frontend and backend. Users / bots can bypass the frontend and send the HTTP requests directly to the backend. Counting on the backend might seem more robust, but if you are interested in UI interactions, you should count on the frontend.

Comment: simply use a count function of java and JS to record your counts, and save it in the database or wherever you want.

Comment: what Java libraries do you recommend to ensure consistency to handle multiple transactions concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

This type of functionality is best implemented using AOP like AspectJ or Java Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think storing on the back-end will be best, looking through your text and making mentions of Analytics, I figured you want a permanent storage for the number of clicks all through the life time of the app, won't advise you track details on the front end , because those values are temporary and won't be stored on your server, then because more than one user will be using the web application. Would advice you make a call to a back-end function which increases a stored value every time there is a click on the button website. It may be best to use a noSQL db to store it since all you want to do is to increment the values and also because of performance.

But then when you start having several users, accessing the website from different location and simultaneously you may have to manage concurrency issue that may arise

Comment: what Java libraries do you recommend to ensure consistency to handle multiple transactions concurrently?